# How to use win32api package to send to printer a file in memory

Tags: python, angular, printing, websocket, in-memory

I have an Angular application that is communicating via websocket with a python app. 
Actually, I save the file in Angular, then I pass to the websocket the file path and I print it by win32api.ShellExecute.

Anyway, I do not really need to save the file, so would be much better to send the content though the websocket and then then print it.

Can anyone send me some code snippet to show:

1. Which is the best data structure to receive the file content via websocket (bytes array?)
2. How to invoke win32api.ShellExecute, or equivalent function, to print the content.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is not completed. How you save file in Angular? Angular sends it to web server? What file path you send to the back-end? It means, that Angular actually don't send file to web server. Then you're saying, you use win32api.ShellExecute to print it, but also asking for a code snippet for this. What?

Comment: Sorry for the question not explicit. I do not want to save the file (that’s why I do not explain how I do it). 
So first question is: how to send the in memory content (a javascript Blob) directly to the python via web socket?
And then, win32api.ShellExecute accepts as a parameter a file path; is there an equivalent function that accept an in memory data?

Comment: Why do you want to send files over WebSockets instead of POST requests? I think, WebSockets have no advantages in this case. I recommend you to save files in a temporary folder, but if you want to store them in memory, then the easiest way will be to use virtual RAM drive (you can google different software for this, but I can't suggest you something concrete). Using virtual RAM drive all your files will be in memory and also you can use `ShellExecute` function like before.

Comment: I use websocket to have a bidirectional communication between Angular app and a simple Python service (for serial port notifications, printing, etc.).